# Include not working in EntityFramework 6.0?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this three model in my databse:

```
public class Parent{
    public Child B {get; set;}
    //  ....more properties....
}

public class Child{
    public City City {get; set;}
    // ....more properties....
}

public class City {
    public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

now I want to get all parent including its children and also city of children using this code:

```
using (var ctx = new DataBaseCtx())
        {
            var result = ctx.Parents.Include(x => x.B.City)
           .Select(x => new ParentDTO
            {
                B= x.B,
                // .... other properties ....
            }).ToList();
        }
```

but when i try to access to result.B.City this is null...
where is wrong in my code or approach?

Comment: `.Include()` doesn't work with projectons

Comment: is there any solution to achieve this goal?

Comment: you can explicitly load `City` as a property of your `ParentDTO` object via `City = x.City` inside object initializer

Comment: it is so weird.... why there is no cleaner and better solution???

Comment: Using projections you're requesting granular control over everything so you receive it. Just don't use projections and then life will be easier, grass greener etc

Comment: i try to use your solution but i am getting Disposed Object exception

Comment: You might need to copy every property you need in result

Answer (score 0):

You have to include your child class before calling city

```
 var result = ctx.Parents.Include(x => x.Child).Include(y=>y.City).ToList();
```